# React.js and Websocket.io ends up in infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, use-effect

i want to write a game Lobby for a card game.
Using React.js, Node.js and Websocket.io for achieving this.
As so far all went fine. Players are connected in the same Lobby.
But i want to print in the Lobby sth Like (Player 1: Steven, Player 2: Frank, ...).
I ended up in an infinite loop, i am trying to solve since hours.
So maybe someone can help me. It keeps re-rendering by useState i guess, but i don't know how to prevent it from.

Relevant Frontend Code:

```
const Lobby = (props) => {
  const socket = props.socket;
  const player = {
    room: props.room,
    name: props.name,
  };

  const [playerList, setPlayerList] = useState([]);

  socket.emit("joined_lobby", player);
  console.log(`${playerList}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("add_user", (data) => {
      setPlayerList([...playerList, data.name]);
    });
  }, []);
```

Relevant Server Code:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {   console.log(`Player with ID:\[${socket.id}\] Connected`);

  socket.on("join_room", (data) => {
    socket.join(data);
    console.log(`Player with ID:\[${socket.id}\] Joined the room ${data}`);   });

  socket.on("joined_lobby", (data) => {
    socket.to(data.room).emit("add_user", data);   });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(`Player with ID:\[${socket.id}\] Disonnected`);   }); });
```

Comment: Maybe i should add: I understand the principle, that with every change in the Playerlist the code gets executed again, which ends up in the infinite loop, because the socket.emit("joined_lobby", player); code is also run again. I just don't know how to prevent this

Answer (score 0):

i would like to say i am currently passing through quite the same challenge, looking out for the solution

Comment: Your answer does not really answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you only want to run `socket.emit("joined_lobby", player);` once per 'player'.

If so, move it into a useEffect, and make it so it runs only if the room or player name changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
 const player = {
    room: props.room,
    name: props.name,
  };

   socket.emit("joined_lobby", player);
   
  return () => {
    // I invented this - you need a way of dealing with leaving
    // e.g. if the room changes
    socket.emit("left_lobby", player);
  } 
  
},[props.room, props.name]);
```

EDIT: you may need to put props.socket in the deps too - I don't know how the lifecycle of that one works

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error as you and after 2 hours of fixing the error I found out that I opened 2 accounts to chat with each other and one of those 2 I didn't refresh, causing it to be infinity connect